# how to use variable value as html hyperlink text

Tags: html, pug

```
>  "<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Visit our HTML
> tutorial</a>"
```

---

For example for above html code.

I don't want "Visit our HTML tutorial", I want to use my variable 'a' to set it.
How should I do it?

Edit:
what I have is actually a jade code.

```
  form(method='post', action="/poll2")
    each val in [['Chipotle','chipole' ],['Todai','todai-fairfax']]
      input(type='radio', value= val.toString(), name='chosen_restraunt')
      a(href='http://www.yelp.com/biz/'+val[1]) val[0]

      br
```

Everything works fine excpet the `val[0]` shows "val[0]" on my page, not the value I want to see, for example "Chipotle"
How can I fix this？
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'use my variable a to set it'? by variable a do you mean the anchor tag?

Comment: i mean, I don't want to hard code a string in my html code.

Comment: Have you tried using Javascript?

Comment: or any server side script?

Comment: not able to understand , this variable is in js or where? please make it little bit clear and share some code

Answer (score 0):

I have found my solution:

```
  form(method='post', action="/poll")
    each val in [['Chipotle','chipotle-mexican-grill-fairfax-5' ],['Todai','todai-fairfax'], ['Mandarin',''], ['HongkongTast 大排档 ',''],['China88','']]
      input(type='radio', value= val.toString(), name='chosen_restraunt')
      a(href='http://www.yelp.com/biz/'+val[1])  #{val[0]}
      br
```